# Issue creating rootReducer with combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router-redux

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducers } from './reducers';
import { IAppAction } from './action';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { IAppState } from './state/app-state';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router: routerReducer
});

export const rootReducer = (state: IAppState, action: IAppAction) => {
    return appReducer(state, action)
};
```

I am getting the below error

```
"Argument of type 'IAppState' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ router: RouterState; app: any; }'.
  Type 'IAppState' is missing the following properties from type '{ router: RouterState; app: any; }': router, app"
```

Uploaded sample to [github](https://github.com/tharaka86/react-template)

package versions

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"typescript": "3.5.3"
```

Exact same code worked on my older project

```
"react": "^16.8.4",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"typescript": "^3.3.4000"
```

Comment: Can you create a small app to reproduce this in codesandbox.io and share the link?

Comment: This seems circular to me,  how are you creating `store`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I have pushed it to git. Please find it here https://github.com/tharaka86/react-template
this file is under `react-template/src/store/`

Answer (score 0):

Simpler fix would be you need to add missing types in your `IAppState` to include router which you need based on your combineReducers code, and `app: any` which I believe would be your `IAppState` instead of `any`

May be create to manage it better and not pollute your IAppState where you may not need router based on your use-case/code

```
interface IAppStateWithRouter extends IAppState = {
  router: RouterState
}
```

And your rootReducer becomes

`export const rootReducer = (state: IAppStateWithRouter, action: IAppAction) => {`